# Managing Development and Production Dockerfiles

Tags: docker

This is my current setup for my project and I was wondering if there was a more elegant way. The current setup is as follows.

Directory structure

```
<root>
 - Dockerfile_base   # base image for the other two
 - Dockerfile_dev    # development image
 - Dockerfile_prod   # production image
 - Makefile
```

The Dockerfiles:

```
# Dockerfile_base   
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.4.1-gpu
RUN pip install ...
```

```
# Dockerfile_dev
FROM eu.gcr.io/cool_project/cool_program_base:latest
RUN pip install <dev branch of this repo>
```

```
# Dockerfile_prod
FROM eu.gcr.io/cool_project/cool_program_base:latest
RUN pip install <master branch of this repo>
```

Makefile

```
deploybase:
    docker build -f Dockerfile_base -t cool_program_base:latest .
    docker tag cool_program_base:latest eu.gcr.io/cool_project/cool_program_base
    docker push eu.gcr.io/cool_project/cool_program_base

deploydev:
    docker build -f Dockerfile_dev -t cool_program_dev:latest .
    docker tag cool_program_dev:latest eu.gcr.io/cool_project/cool_program_dev
    docker push eu.gcr.io/cool_project/cool_program_dev

deployprod:
    docker build -f Dockerfile_prod -t cool_program_prod:latest .
    docker tag cool_program_prod:latest eu.gcr.io/cool_project/cool_program_prod
    docker push eu.gcr.io/cool_project/cool_program_prod
```

Q1: Is there a way to combine the three Dockerfiles into a single one? I know that there are multistage builds but I could not find how to make this work.
Q2: If it is possible, can the Makefile also be written more compactly?

Comment: Can you use the same dockerfile for all environments? (i.e. keep the differences in environment variables that can be set when running the containers)

Comment: I like that idea. I would have to think about that, if it is really possible, but up until now I did not consider this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the docker images, you could use [build-args](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg), that is having a single parametrized Dockerfile:

```
ARG BRANCH=dev-branch
FROM eu.gcr.io/cool_project/cool_program_base:latest
RUN pip install $BRANCH
```

Then:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile --build-arg BRANCH=master -t cool_program_prod:latest .
```

or

```
docker build -f Dockerfile --build-arg BRANCH=dev -t cool_program_dev:latest .
```

You actually do not need to push "cool_program_base" image, because its layers are already included in both of the dev and prod images.